# Robolectric java heap size error

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, out-of-memory, robolectric

So I am running my tests using Robolectric 3.1.4. In another project I had no problems running all my test with robolectric, but right now I always get this error:

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

When I remove some views of the activity, the problem stops...

Well, my question is: How can I increase the heap size in the project or how can I make robolectric consume less memory?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hard to say what can be the issue: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1700, https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2068

Comment: Also usage of jdk8 instead of jdk7 might help, unless you're already on it

Comment: I am using jdk8. The test is really small and the class is also very small... It is really wierd... I'll show you in a little time.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem usually happens when you're displaying too many images on your activities. Probably using some ViewPager? If that's the case, you can read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html#viewpager), which explains how to use cache to store images and reduce memory consumption.

Another solution is increasing the heap size, by setting this on the AndroidManifest.xml: `android:largeHeap=”true”` .. But keep in mind that this is used mostly on apps that require a lot of memory like games, video processors, etc

Comment: No images. The problem doesnt happens in my device, only when running the robolectric tests

Comment: Can you tell us which views you're removing to see the problem stoping?

Comment: Sorry It is taking ages for me to reply... I was a little busy. I will put the project in github and publish the code in my question in some hours.

Answer (score 0):

the answer should be(at least for me):

in build.gradle(Project:xxx), add as below:

```
subprojects {
  tasks.withType(Test) {
    maxParallelForks = 2
    forkEvery = 80
    maxHeapSize = "2048m"
    minHeapSize = "1024m"
  }
}
```

refer from:https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/5131